# Making a simple calculator using while

Tags: python

Make a calculator that should add multiple numbers taken from input and output the result.

The number of inputs is variable and should stop when the user enters "stop".

Sample Input

```
4
32
6
stop
```

Sample Output

```
42
```

Use an infinite loop to take user input and break it, if the input equals to "stop".

here is my code

```
sum = 0
while True:
  
   #your code goes here
    x = int(input())
    print(sum)
    sum += x
    if x == stop:
        print(sum)
        break

print("Finished")
```

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: What have you tried? Please see [ask] and provide a [mre]. SO is not a free coding service

Comment: Ok,  I see you have added some code. What do you think about it? Are there any problems?

Comment: yes, its compiling successfully, but can not pass the test cases

Comment: Ok, you have test cases! Cool! Please can you update your question with a couple of test cases?

Comment: Test Case 1

Input
1
2
3
4
5
stop

Expected Output
15

Comment: remaining test cases are Locked

Comment: Ok, that's fine. So you say `cannot pass the test cases`. What is the outcome? Did you try these test cases manually yourself?

Comment: Yes, I did around multiple times

Comment: Ok, so what is the outcome for each?

Comment: Test Case failed

Comment: How do you know they failed? Did you see some output which is not expected?

Comment: yes i did, it prompted at the end of excution

Comment: Well, you've either not posted the code you actually use or you're getting an error traceback. Which is it?

Comment: the error traceback now sorted everything! thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few corrections to make:

1. **Don't** ever use inbuilt functions as variables. `sum` is inbuilt function
2. `if x == stop`, the `stop` has no quotes, so python will consider that as a variable. But `stop` is not defined. So a `NameError` will be raised
3. You should not convert the input to a integer directly. If you write `stop`, `int()` cannot convert that to an integer (it's obvious) so a `ValueError` is raised. Instead, convert `x` to a integer before adding it.
4. Add the value to the variable in the `else` part. If you write `stop`, some errors would be raised.

```
sum1 = 0
while True:
    x = input()
    if x == 'stop':
        print(sum1)
        break
    else:
        sum1 += int(x)

print("Finished")
```

Comment: Thank you, i see where i did the mistake!

Comment: @SairamMuralidharan Most welcome, consider accepting and upvoting the answer